# Using Ajax request on Override AdminOrdersController in PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: ajax, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I saw similar topics, but it did not help :(

PS: 1.6.1.1

Overview:
Is there any "magic" code that override of AdminOrdersController must include to gets ajax request (jQuery) ?

Details:
I have Ajax request called on Orders List page. When this request is "reciced" by function located in **oryginal** AdminOrdersController , it runs fine !

But just when I move the function **that gets the call from Ajax**, to separated file in /override/controllers/admin/ , it fails. -> no answer from request.

Why ???

I suppose I should add something that "gives" URL for Ajax, but I don't know what...

Thanks in advace !

This is JS with Ajax request. It works even without URL parameter, becouse it calls the currant page.

```
$(function() {   $('.notice_show').on('click', function() {
   var $scope = $(this);
   var $tr = $scope.closest('tr');
   var $length = $tr.find('td').length;
   var $ajax_run = null;
   var $element = null;
   var $notice_show_content = null;

   if (!$scope.data('show')) {
       $scope.data('show', true);
       $tr.after('<tr class="not_show"><td colspan="'+$length+'"><span class="not_show_ajax_running"><i class="icon-refresh icon-spin icon-fw"></i></span><span class="notice_show_content"></span></td></tr>');
       $element = $tr.next('.not_show');
       $notice_show_content = $element.find('.notice_show_content');
       $ajax_run = $element.find('.not_show_ajax_running');
       $ajax_run.show();
       $.ajax({   
           data: {
               get_notice: true,
               id_order: $scope.attr('attr-id')
           },
           dataType: 'json',
           type: 'POST',
           success: function($response) {
               if ($response.error) {
                   $.notify($response.error, 'error', 2000);
               } else {
                   $notice_show_content.html($response.content);
               }
           },
           complete: function() {
               $ajax_run.hide();
           }
       });
   } else {
       $scope.data('show', false);
       $tr.next('.not_show').remove();
   }
```

});
});

This is function added to AdminOrdersController. It works ONLY IF it's added to the oryginal file. If it's in override folder it fails.

```
  public function renderList()
{

return parent::renderList();

   if (Tools::isSubmit('get_notice') && ($id_order = Tools::getValue('id_order', NULL))) {
                $result = array(
                    'error' => false,
                    'content' => ''
                );
                $order = new Order($id_order);
                if (Validate::isLoadedObject($order)) {
                    $notices = NoticeOrder::get($order->id);
                    if ($notices) {
                        foreach($notices as &$notice) {
                            $emp = new Employee($notice->id_employee);
                            if (Validate::isLoadedObject($emp)) {
                                $notice->employee = $emp->firstname . ' ' . $emp->lastname;
                            } else {
                                $notice->employee = '';
                            }
                        }
                        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                            'notice' => $notices,
                            'not_add' => true
                        ));

                        $result['content'] = $this->createTemplate('_notice.tpl')->fetch();

                        $address = new Address($order->id_address_delivery);

                        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($address)) {
                            if ($address->other) {
                                $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                                    'addresses' => array(
                                        'delivery' => $address
                                    ),
                                ));
                                $result['content'] .= $this->createTemplate('_other.tpl')->fetch();
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        $result['error'] = $this->l('Notice not found');
                    }
                } else {
                    $result['error'] = $this->l('Order not found');
                }

                echo Tools::jsonEncode($result);
                die;
             }

}
```

Comment: post here the code of overriden controller

Comment: It is long but the only function that recives ajax is below:

`public function renderList()
    {
    return parent::renderList();
     
       if (Tools::isSubmit('get_notice') && ($id_order = Tools::getValue('id_order', NULL))) {

                /*some clouses to build data for $result}*/

   } else {
    $result['error'] = $this->l('Notice not found');
      }
      } else {
     $result['error'] = $this->l('Order not found');
  }
    echo Tools::jsonEncode($result);
  die;
}
}`

Comment: And here is the Ajax:
 $.ajax({
               data: {
                   get_notice: true,
                   id_order: $scope.attr('attr-id')
               },
               dataType: 'json',
               type: 'POST',
  success: function($response) {
 if ($response.error) {
  $.notify($response.error, 'error', 2000);
  } else {
   $notice_show_content.html($response.content);
   }
   },
 complete: function() {
     $ajax_run.hide();
     }
 });

**It all works if only the controller code is added to oryginal AdminOrderController.php**

Comment: Sorry, I put the code as comment, I didn't notice the EDIT button on ask form :) do now it's more usefull to read !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here and not related with AJAX

```
public function renderList()
{

return parent::renderList(); // !!! code below this line will not work
...
```

Comment: Oooo, f**K ! You are totally rght !. I was so focused on ajax that forgot to move this line to bottom.... Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check network monitor (ctrl+shift+q)? Can you post status result of your ajax post? But it is clear. Just change ajax post URL to override path not to original controller.

For example:

url: base_url+'/modules/ols/ajax.php', but add full path to your file (override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php).

After this check again POSt status.

Comment: Yes, I've tried different URL combinations but it not help. When the URL (with full path) is to AdminOrdersController.php it results error 404. Only if the URL is to the original AdminController (with token) or if there is NO url, the status is 200 and the whole ajax works.

Comment: Yes, it was posted as a second comment of my quastion here. By the way, do you know how can I post here code more usefull to read ? Becouse in comment it's like in the book :)